# Reading strings doesn't work

Tags: c, string, malloc

I have this little code and I really can't figure out why it always gives me SIGSEGVs.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int read_strs(char **a, int *len) {

  int i;
  scanf("%d", len);
  if(*len <= 0) return 1;
  a = (char **) malloc(sizeof(char*) * (*len));
  if(a == NULL) return 1;
  for( i = 0; i < *len; i++ ) 
  {
      a[i] = malloc(sizeof(char) * 1000);
      scanf("%s", a[i]);
  }

  return 0;

}


int main(void) {
  int i, n;
  char **array;

  read_strs(array, &n);
  for( i = 0; i < n; i++ ) 
    printf("%s\n", array[i]);
    return 0;
}
```

It seems it doesn't even alloc the memory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `char ** array;` in your main function never gets loaded with the char ** array you malloc in test. You send a copy of the pointer to read_strs - it won't get updated when you assign to it here:

```
// a is local to test_str
a = (char **) malloc(sizeof(char*) * (*len));
```

You would need to pass a pointer to your `char ** array` variable if you want it to work in your current scheme. You could also simply return `a` from `read_strs`.

**edit**: note, if you pass a pointer to `char ** array`, you'll also have to do work to make read_strs operate on a pointer to a `char **`, whereas now it's operating on a simple `char **`.

Comment: To still return a int value, should I make a char*** array in my the read_strs and change the function's code with *a instead of just "a" ?

Comment: Right, I added an edit to my answr, and @Dinesh explained it in code, using a local variable `char ** a` so that you don't have to update your function, besides the header which he's updated to `char ***ax`

Comment: Thanks. Without using a new alias like Dinesh did, remember to use (*a)[i] instead of *a[i] (just writing in case anybody else will struggle with it too :) )

Answer (score 1):

You need a couple fixes, but basically Walter is right

```
 int read_strs(char***ax, *len){
```

then

```
char **a;
a = *ax = (char**) malloc(sizeof(char*) * (*len));
```

then in the call, pass the location of `array` so that it can be filled by the function:

```
read_strs(&array, &n);
```

Comment: Thank you, that alias would've made it easier :)